# Bluetooth headset not discovered

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, bluetooth-speaker

I tried connecting my bluetooth headset to my Ubuntu 19.04 but didn't succeeded. However, it is able to connect my android phone and my android phone is able to connect my BT headset. So, there is probably any problem between my laptop and BT headset. I've tried almost every method available on internet but none of them helped. Please help!

Comment: Please edit your question and post output of the following commands: 1. `sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service`, 2. `sudo systemctl is-enabled bluetooth.service` 3. `cat /etc/bluetooth/main.conf | grep -i -E 'DiscoverableTimeout|AutoEnable'` 4. `sudo lshw | grep -i -A6 "description: Bluetooth"` 5. `dmesg | grep -i bluetooth` 6. `rfkill` and 7. `pulseaudio --check -v`. Thanks.